How can I pass "streaming" (i.e., Server-Sent Events) from a Blazor service back to the calling .RAZOR page?
I have a blazor application that I am using to have a conversation with MistralAI.
When prompted, MistralAI will use Server-Sent Events to "stream" data back.
On my .RAZOR page, after a users enters their query, I have this:
<div>
    <EditForm Model="this" OnValidSubmit="@QueryAI">
        <input type="text" />
    </EditForm>
</div>
@code {
    StreamingQueryResponse streamingResponse = await service.getStreamingResponseAsync(conversation);
    String word = streamingResponse.choices[0].delta.content;
}

I have a service, registered with the application that calls MistralAI:
public async Task<StreamingQueryResponse> getStreamingResponseAsync(Conversation conversation)
{
    try
    {
        string requestString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(conversation);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await opService.StreamingPostAsync("http://my.endpoint/", content);
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using Stream responseStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        bool go = true;
        do
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0) break;
            string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            try
            {As 
                var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StreamingQueryResponse>(response);
                if (jsonString.choices != null)
                {
                    // At this point, I am getting all of the tokens (words) from the LLM.
                    // I just need to figure out how to send those to the .RAZOR page without "return"-ing.
                    // Console.WriteLine(jsonString.choices[0].delta.content);
                    go = (jsonString.choices[0].finish_reason == null);
                    return jsonString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        } while (go);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}

The opService:
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> StreamingPostAsync(string uri, HttpContent content = null)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        Content = content
    };
    request.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");

    HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(uri);
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    return httpResponse;
}

As my comment in the code snippet above states, when I put a Console.WriteLine() within the "if" statement of my service, I see the stream coming back from MistralAI. However, I cannot figure out how to get that stream back to the .RAZOR page so I can display the "live" chat.
When I use return I, obviously, just get the first word back, and that's it.
How do I go about doing this?
